# Bootstrap: How to designate left/right columns

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I have a product details page in which I want the product **image/first Col to be on top on mobile devices**, and on the **right side for desktop**. I read through the grid docs but was unable to find anything. The code below places it on top on mobile, but on the left for desktop, and when I switch them it puts the image on the right for desktop, but on bottom for mobile. I'm using react-bootstrap:

```
<Row>
  <div className="col-md-6">
    <img src={thisProduct.image} alt={thisProduct.name}/>
  </div>
  <div className="col-md-6 product-detail-card-text">
    <Card.Title>{thisProduct.name}</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>{thisProduct.price}</Card.Text>
    <Card.Text>Quantity: {thisProduct.quantity}</Card.Text>
    <Card.Text>Description: {thisProduct.description}</Card.Text>
  </div>
</Row>
```

Comment: If you want to put your image in right side then where you want to put your description?

Comment: mobile: image: top, description: bottom // desktop: description left, image right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use Flexbox in this case:

```
<Row className="product">
  <div className="product--image">
    <img src={thisProduct.image} alt={thisProduct.name}/>
  </div>
  <div className="product--details">
    <Card.Title>{thisProduct.name}</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>{thisProduct.price}</Card.Text>
    <Card.Text>Quantity: {thisProduct.quantity}</Card.Text>
    <Card.Text>Description: {thisProduct.description}</Card.Text>
  </div>
</Row>
```

And then the CSS like this (defining the screen size that will apply your order switch):

```
.product {
   display: flex;
}

.product--image {
   order: 1;
}

.product--detail {
   order: 2;
   @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
      order: 0;
   }
}
```

If you want to test more the order property:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_order

And to know more about Flexbox (which I highly recommend): https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Previously wasn't aware of order. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this solution:

```
<Row className="d-block d-sm-block d-md-none d-lg-none">
  <div className="col-md-6">
    <img src={thisProduct.image} alt={thisProduct.name}/>
  </div>
  <div className="col-md-6 product-detail-card-text">
    <Card.Title>{thisProduct.name}</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>{thisProduct.price}</Card.Text>
    <Card.Text>Quantity: {thisProduct.quantity}</Card.Text>
    <Card.Text>Description: {thisProduct.description}</Card.Text>
  </div>
</Row>


<Row className="d-none d-sm-none d-md-block d-lg-block">
  <div className="col-md-6 product-detail-card-text">
    <Card.Title>{thisProduct.name}</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>{thisProduct.price}</Card.Text>
    <Card.Text>Quantity: {thisProduct.quantity}</Card.Text>
    <Card.Text>Description: {thisProduct.description}</Card.Text>
  </div>
  <div className="col-md-6">
    <img src={thisProduct.image} alt={thisProduct.name}/>
  </div>
</Row>
```

Otherwise for desktop you will not get your desired solution.
I think you know about `d-block d-none etc`